# Run T test on merged values in rows of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I'd like to take the two columns of merged values in my dataframe and run a t-test on each row between x_and y_merged_psi_values. I would then like to append the t and p values to the end of the original df. My actual starting dataframe is much larger, but this is an example of the layout:

```
In [3]: df=pd.DataFrame({'chromosome':[1,1,5], 
   ...:                  'strand':['-','-','+'], 
   ...:                  'elementloc':[4991, 8870, 2703], 
   ...:                  'x_Merged_Psi_values': ['0.21, 0.25,0.63,0.92','0.3, 0.
   ...:6, 0.78, 0.9', '0.39, 0.11, 0.09, 0.94'], 
   ...:                  'y_Merged_Psi_values':['0.11, 0.45, nan', '0.45, 0.22, 
   ...: 0.89', '0.17, 0.12, 0.64']}) 
   ...: df         

                                                         

Out[3]: 
   chromosome strand  elementloc     x_Merged_Psi_values y_Merged_Psi_values
0           1      -        4991    0.21, 0.25,0.63,0.92     0.11, 0.45, nan
1           1      -        8870    0.3, 0.56, 0.78, 0.9    0.45, 0.22, 0.89
2           5      +        2703  0.39, 0.11, 0.09, 0.94    0.17, 0.12, 0.64
```

I know how to do this for one row, but need help automating this through the rest of the rows, especially since I know iterating through pandas dataframe rows is not advised.

Here is what I am doing for one row. I'd like to do this for all of the rows and append the resulting t and p values to df.

```
X_psi=df["x_Merged_Psi_values"].to_list()
X_psi = [i.split(',') for i in X_psi]
X_psi = [ x for x in X_psi[0] if str(x) != 'nan']
X_psi = [float(i) for i in X_psi]
X_psi

Y_psi=df["y_Merged_Psi_values"].to_list()
Y_psi = [i.split(',') for i in Y_psi]
Y_psi = [ x for x in Y_psi[0] if str(x) != 'nan']
Y_psi = [float(i) for i in Y_psi]
Y_psi

t, p = ttest_ind(X_psi, Y_psi, equal_var=False)
print("Ttest_ind:      t=%g  p=%g" %(t,p))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get away without looping, since every row needs a separate T-test. Just a suggestion for the same code:

```
X_psi = [[float(x) for x in row.split(',') if x!='nan'] for row in df.x_Merged_Psi_values]
Y_psi = [[float(x) for x in row.split(',') if x!='nan'] for row in df.y_Merged_Psi_values]
t_list, p_list = [], []
for X, Y in zip(X_psi, Y_psi):
    t, p = ttest_ind(X, X, equal_var=False)
    #print("Ttest_ind:      t=%g  p=%g" %(t,p))
    t_list.append(t)
    p_list.append(p_list)
df = df.assign(t_values=t_list, p_values=p_list)
```

Also, take a look at [Series.str.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html). If all rows have roughly the same amount of items after being split then it can be easier to:

```
df.x_Merged_Psi_values = df.x_Merged.Psi_values.str.split(pat=',')
df.y_Merged_Psi_values = df.y_Merged_Psi_values.str.split(pat=',')
for X, Y in zip(df.x_Merged_Psi_values, df.y_Merged_Psi_values):
    t, p = ttest_ind(map(float, X), map(float, Y), equal_var=False)
    # and the rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm having a trouble with the first part: unmerging/splitting up each row of strings. Your suggestion joins all the rows together, which prevents me from accurately running the t test. Is there a way to split up each row into its own list?

Comment: My mistake, just edited the list comprehension... try it now